# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at /courses/course_list.html

Tags: python, django, django-templates, settings

i am get this warning while running  the code below:

here is the image output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/defEU.png)

while in browser its showing 1.11.1
this is my pycharm project interpreter setting
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuvvj.png)

its creating bit confusing 
i am running 2.03 or 1.11.1

course_list.py

```
{% for course in courses %}
<h2>{{course.title}}</h2>
{{course.description}}
{% endfor %}
```

courses\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.course_list ),
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Course

admin.site.register(Course)
```

view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Course


def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'courses/course_list.html',
                  {'courses': courses})
```

trackback

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\parad\tiger\heil\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\parad\tiger\heil\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\parad\tiger\heil\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\parad\tiger\heil\learning_site\courses\views.py in course_list
                  {'courses': courses}) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\parad\tiger\heil\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\parad\tiger\heil\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in render_to_string
        template = get_template(template_name, using=using) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\parad\tiger\heil\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
```

Comment: You are using `1.11.1`. PyCharm is just _showing_ you that the latest version is something else.

Comment: What is the setting `TEMPLATES` in your `settings.py`? Also, what is the absolute path of `course_list.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , try running "django-admin --version" in pycharm terminal it will show you the output and also check that your html file is in template folder in you app directory if you didn't change the path of template directory.

Comment: i check it its 1.11.1 i make few changes now its working fine thanks. but i have installed 2.0.3 using pip command . how to update it on  pycharm ?

Comment: Check weather your pycharm has same python interpreter selected where you install  django 2.0.3